# Probability of event in 3 hours, what time period has 99% confidence that event will occur

Tags: probability, statistics

A table of significant wave height includes the probability of the wave height occurring during a three hour period, with probabilities ranging from $0.05\%$ to $27.8\%$.  My questions are:

1) How much time till the next significant wave occurs?

2) how often does the significant wave occur during a longer time period (week, month or year)?

Is this as simple as the following

P_not_3h = 1 - P_3h

P_not_TP = (1 - P_3h)^(TP_hr/3)

P_TP = 1-P_not_TP

TP_99 = 0.99 = 1- (1 - P_3h)^(TP_hr/3)

TP_hr = 3*ln(1-0.99) / ln(1 - P_3h)

therefore

1) TP_hr = 3*ln(1-0.99) / ln(1 - P_3h)

2) ?

Comment: I think you should clarify your question and add some more details. For example, can you show this table?

Comment: The table is from NATO STANAG 4194, North Atlantic Open Ocean, but I'm not sure where to find it online.